# How to set line color & fill color in spiderweb chart

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am using highchart to create a spider web chart. I wanted to add a fill color & opacity like the image I have added below. I have tried the following code. But that didn't work.

[Using this chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider)

[image: Chart Design]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `chart.backgroundColor`, `series.color` and `series.fillOpacity` for the area series. For example:

```
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'line',
        backgroundColor: '#07292c'
    },
    series: [{
        color: '#30bb00',
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        type: 'area',
        ...
    }, {
        color: '#71c6d1',
        ...
    }, {
        color: '#d1be75',
        ...
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t7mkvq1u/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.backgroundColor

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.fillOpacity